quickfix.FieldException: Tag not defined for this message type, field=447
I have an already defined field in data dictionary XML. But QuickFIXJ throw exception Rejecting invalid message.
Also, I already added allow unknown message fields Y.
FIX MSG:
8=FIXT.1.1�9=226�35=9�49=FGW�56=CLIENT.FIX�34=3�52=20241122-05:05:45.258�1128=9�11=14411�37=NONE�453=1�448=CLIENT.FIX�447=D�452=53�39=8�434=1�102=1�58=Order not found (too late to cancel or unknown order)�60=20241122-05:05:45.206�1180=1�30001=1�10=097
My config:
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
UseDataDictionary=Y
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateUserDefinedMessages=N
HeartBtInt=30
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID= TEST
TargetCompID=FGW
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=1011
SocketConnectHost=localhost
DataDictionary=./data_dictionary.xml
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

Message Data dictionary:

...
    <message name="OrderCancelReject" msgtype="9" msgcat="app">
            <field name='OrderID' required='Y' />
            <field name='SecondaryOrderID' required='N' />
            <field name='SecondaryClOrdID' required='N' />
            <field name='ClOrdID' required='Y' />
            <field name='ClOrdLinkID' required='N' />
            <field name='OrigClOrdID' required='N' />
            <field name='OrdStatus' required='Y' />
            <field name='WorkingIndicator' required='N' />
            <field name='OrigOrdModTime' required='N' />
            <field name='ListID' required='N' />
            <field name='Account' required='N' />
            <field name='AcctIDSource' required='N' />
            <field name='AccountType' required='N' />
            <field name='TradeOriginationDate' required='N' />
            <field name='TradeDate' required='N' />
            <field name='TransactTime' required='N' />
            <field name='CxlRejResponseTo' required='Y' />
            <field name='CxlRejReason' required='N' />
            <field name='Text' required='N' />
            <field name='EncodedTextLen' required='N' />
            <field name='EncodedText' required='N' />
            <field name='PartyIDSource' required='N' />
            <field name='PartyID' required='N' />
            <field name='NoPartyIDs' required='N' />
            <field name='PartyRole' required='N' />
            <field name='ApplID' required='N' />
            <field name='UserDefinedTag' required='N' />
        </message>
...
<field number="447" name="PartyIDSource" type="STRING"/>

I already setup my java application. I can logon into Acceptor. Therefore, I can send new order, cancel order requests. But I can not decode message.
How to correctly configure my application?

That is a repeating group that you are trying to add. But you are adding it as flat fields. Take a look here how it should be added to the message:
https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/b25f34734fdae88189498cb8e7e658a53bd0fc9b/quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2/src/main/resources/FIX50SP2.modified.xml#L1975
<component name="Parties" required="N"/>

And then here the definition of the component, please adapt fields as needed.
https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/b25f34734fdae88189498cb8e7e658a53bd0fc9b/quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2/src/main/resources/FIX50SP2.modified.xml#L5265-L5272
<component name="Parties"> 
   <group name="NoPartyIDs" required="N"> 
     <field name="PartyID" required="N"/> 
     <field name="PartyIDSource" required="N"/> 
     <field name="PartyRole" required="N"/> 
   </group> 
 </component> 


In case it helps, here is an example on how to add the Parties group into an ExecutionReport:
    final Parties parties = new Parties();
    final Parties.NoPartyIDs executingFirmParty = new Parties.NoPartyIDs();
    executingFirmParty.set(new PartyID(BROKER_ID));
    executingFirmParty.set(new PartyIDSource(PartyIDSource.GENERALLY_ACCEPTED_MARKET_PARTICIPANT_IDENTIFIER));
    executingFirmParty.set(new PartyRole(PartyRole.EXECUTING_FIRM));
    parties.addGroup(executingFirmParty);

    final Parties.NoPartyIDs contraParty = new Parties.NoPartyIDs();
    contraParty.set(new PartyID(CONTRA_FIRM_MPID));
    contraParty.set(new PartyIDSource(PartyIDSource.GENERALLY_ACCEPTED_MARKET_PARTICIPANT_IDENTIFIER));
    contraParty.set(new PartyRole(PartyRole.CONTRA_FIRM));
    parties.addGroup(contraParty);
    executionReport.set(parties);

